# How (and should) I verify that an async internal method was called in State Unit Testing?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, testing, mocking

```
   override fun getSomething(): LiveData<List<Content>> {
        fakeDataSource.fetchSomethingAsync()
        return contentDao.getSomething()
    }
```

Here we have a repository method to get some data remotely, and in the meantime return some livedata from a Room database. The viewmodel that calls this method in the repository doesn't care that the repository is fetching the data from the network behind the scenes - it just knows that it's getting back some livedata and monitoring it for changes.

Now I have to unit test this method. State based unit testing says that all I care about is the state of the system after the call (while behavior unit testing would absolutely require me to verify the async call). Here the fact that another class (fakeDataSource) is asynchronously changing the state at some later time should be afaik irrelevant to me in the context of the unit test of this particular method(?)

So I return a fake item from my fake dao, and my test looks like:

```
   @Test
    fun getSomething_returnsLocal() {
        val result: LiveData<List<Content>> = testedContentRepository.getSomething()
        result.value?.let {
            assert(it.isNotEmpty())
        }
    }
```

Is this good enough, or should I care in my unit test that there was something else happening here - an async call to the network - and should I be testing it? If the answer to that question is 'yes', is there a way of **unit** testing it without mocking the datasource (given that best practice nowadays is more and more towards fakes over mocks)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to test is a side effect in your `getSomething` function, if you want to test that (It depends on how much you want to couple your test code to implementation code), you can do the following:

- Define some state into the `FakeDataSource`; you can make a boolean value default `false` the first time.
- Then, when your method gets called `fetchSomethingAsync`, you can update the value of that state, for example, to `true`.
- You can then assert if `fakeDataSource.isContentFetched()` is true, which basically reads that value we defined.

You can also use mocks, but as you said, it is better to move towards fakes, **because** I can use the same fake in another test that tests the same behavior; otherwise, if I am using mocks, I have to redefine the logic of verification in each test.

Comment: Thanks! Giving the fake a state of wasCalled is exactly what I needed here. I just need to ensure that the instance is reset before every test